# d3.js mypaths is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to separate my code for easier maintenance and I am doing something wrong.
There is a convention in d3 where you simply assign sections to a variable. I'm trying to do that with the following code, but I get a 'mypaths.attr is not a function error'. What is causing this?

/*code*/

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width", svgWidth)
                                     .attr("height", svgHeight)
                                     .attr("viewBox", svgViewBox)
                                     .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                                     .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                                            svgContainer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
                                                    }))
                                     .append("g");               


var mypaths = d3.json("myJSONURL.com", function(err,data) {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                          .data(data)

                          .enter()
                          .append("path");
    });

var styles = mypaths
                .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
                .attr("d", function (d) { return d.d; })
                .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
                    .style("stroke", "#1C1C1C")
                    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
                    .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
                    .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
                    .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
                    .on("click", handlePathClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

First: you probably want to set `myPaths` to the paths you're drawing (what you're doing right now makes absolutely *no* sense).

Second: everything that depends on `data` must be inside `d3.json` callback (`d3.json` is asynchronous).

Thus, I guess that this is what you want:

```
d3.json("myJSONURL.com", function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    var mypaths = svgContainer.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path");

    var styles = mypaths
        .attr("id", function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            return d.d;
        })
        .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
        .style("stroke", "#1C1C1C")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)
        .on("click", handlePathClick);

});
```

Comment: What I want is to separate out the data line from the attributes. I am able to that in this case:  var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                          .data(jsonCircles)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });